# HTTP: Semantics of breaking webpage information into two pages

Tags: apache, http

I have a webpage whose information had to be split into two separate pages. I want visitors to inform of the fact that there are now two different pages, and thus serve visitors of the old single-page page a custom error page like

```
(Depending on who you are, ) the page you want is either of these:

    *Link to page A*
    *Link to page B*
```

This should be in HTML (to obey the general web site style).

The things that I'm unclear about are semantics and apache configuration

1. What HTTP Status Code to serve? There is `301 Moved Permanently`, but I have more than one alternative to offer.
2. Is it possible to configure apache to my needs without a hacky LocationMatch or similar? Ideally, I would like to use the normal file serving semantics with the exception that the HTTP Status code should not be 200.

Comment: Hey Jo So, I'm a little unclear what you're tying to do. Do you want users to be redirected to *one* interstitial page with *links* to Page A and Page B, or are they immediately directed to one of the two new split pages. If it's the latter, what determines which page they are directed to? Thanks.

Comment: @pieman72: The former: I want to serve them the page describe above (EDIT: Made clearer that these are links). Ideally this shouldn't even be a redirect but simply the old page (content replaced), so no redirection has to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarifying comment.

In answer to your two questions, I'd say:

1. Yes, 301 is the correct response to give. This will say that the old page was moved permanently, and will redirect the user to the interstitial page with the links.
2. You can accomplish this by adding a line to the [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) file in the directory that the old single page was once in (assuming you keep the new page there too). Or you can add a line to your main [httpd.conf file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html). The lines would look like this:

.htaccess

```
Redirect 301 ./old_page.html ./new_interstitial_page.html
```

httpd.conf

```
Redirect 301 /path/to/old_page.html /path/to/new_interstitial_page.html
```

**EDIT :** Without any more context, this really does sound like a redirect scenario. In HTTP terms, the "resource" that was once available at the old location is now available (albeit in parts) at a new location, so you would "redirect" the client to the new location or to the interstitial page.

But if that doesn't seem right to you, you can try a "410 Gone". This says that the resource no longer exists at all, and instead directs the client to an error page. You can then customize the error page to contain links to Page A and Page B. Your .htaccess would look something like this:

```
# Enable URL matching and match the old page with "Gone" (G), "Last rule" (L)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldPage.html$ - [G,L]
</IfModule>

# Special 410 page with links to Page A and Page B
ErrorDocument 410 /path/to/custom/410-page.html
```

Comment: I guess my question is still too unclear. I want the "interstitial" page to be an error page (it should be served with an error code to get it semantically right).

Comment: I have edited my answer to include how to throw an custom error, but I still think this sounds like a redirect scenario. Take that with a grain of salt, though, as I am not in your situation :)